# Gitkraken / Github / git: creating new branch from a non parent branch

Tags: git, github, branch, gitkraken

In my remote repository I have:

```
Origin
feature
abc 
20200801_branch_1
20200802_branch_2
.
.
abc 
develop
```

I want to create a new branch feature/abc/20200811_mybranch with the data from feature/abc/develop. How can I do that??

Thanks!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Several methods ([`checkout -b`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-checkout#Documentation/git-checkout.txt-emgitcheckoutem-b-Bltnewbranchgtltstartpointgt), [`branch`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-branch)) achieve this simple action with nuances :

**1)** you currently have `feature/abc/develop` checked out, you want to create your new branch but stay on `feature/abc/develop`

```
git branch feature/abc/20200811_mybranch
```

**2)** you currently have `feature/abc/develop` checked out, you want to create your new branch AND check it out in the same move

```
git checkout -b feature/abc/20200811_mybranch
```

**3)** you have another branch (let's say `abc`) checked out, you want to create your new branch from `feature/abc/develop` but stay on your current branch

```
git branch feature/abc/20200811_mybranch feature/abc/develop
```

**4)** you have another branch (let's say `abc`) checked out, you want to create your new branch from `feature/abc/develop` AND check out the new branch immediately

```
git checkout -b feature/abc/20200811_mybranch feature/abc/develop
```

Comment: thanks a lot!! I have my branch created locally. I want it to be pushed  it to origin, to Github but pushing it does not create the branch in Github. Am I missing something? Thanks again!

Comment: What command did you type to push? What message did you get?

Comment: I haven't executed it yet: git push feature/abc/20200811_mybranch feature/abc/20200811_mybranch being the first feature/abc/20200811_mybranch on the left the place where I want my local branch to go in Github. Is that correct?

Comment: from your local branch, just do `git push origin HEAD`